# Compare data for 2 columns in access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 columns where column 1 is a substring of column 2. 
How do I create a query in Access displaying result only when there is a match between the 2 columns? 
Thanks for your help!

```
            Column 1    Column 2
               250MG    OLBETAM CAP 250MG X 90
               250MG    OLBETAM CAP 250MG X 90
                10UG    CAVERJECT 10mcg SFDPO 2x1ml DC GB
                10UG    CAVERJECT 20mcg SFDPO 2x1ml DC GB
                10UG    CAVERJECT VIAL 10MCGS
                10UG    CAVERJECT VIAL 20MCGS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instr()` or `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where column2 like "*" & column1 & "*";
```